# Php two forms one page

Tags: php, forms

I have a deleteimage.php page which at the top has includes 'functions.php' <== has all my functions

Okk and in my deleteimage.php page i have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="delForm">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteImg" id="deleteImg" value="Delete Image"/>
    </form>
```

then in my include page i have a function which has:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $images = explode(":", $line);
    if ($user == $images[2]) {
        $imgPath = $images[0];


        $content .= '<div class="private"> <img class="yourGal" src="';
        $content .= $imgPath . '"';
        $content .= 'width="200" alt="$title" /><form action="#" method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="'.$imgPath .'"/>Delete</form></div>';
    }
}
return $content;
```

which basically shows all the pictures you uploaded with a checkbox beside it. Now i have the first form there so i can check as many pictures as i like and click delete to delete them.
Heres my problem, i can't get it to call the $_POST['delete], i have this function to check

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteImg'])) {

echo 'You have selected ' . count($_POST['delete']) . ' images';
}
```

but it says Undefined index: delete at count($_POST['delete']) ??????

Comment: There is no _POST[delete], only _POST[deleteImg], but that is not a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be something like:

```
$content = '<form action="#" method="post" id="delForm">';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $images = explode(":", $line);
    if ($user == $images[2]) {
        $imgPath = $images[0];


        $content .= '<div class="private"> <img class="yourGal" src="';
        $content .= $imgPath . '"';
        $content .= 'width="200" alt="$title" /><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="'.$imgPath .'"/>Delete</div>';
    }
}
content .= '<input type="submit" /></form>';
return $content;
```

Comment: @mario Don't forget to accept MicronXD's answer if it helped you out

Answer (score 1):

The values submitted by a form must be enclosed in the `<form>` tags. Your last form with the submit button has no other fields.

What you should do is

1. Open the `<form>` tag at the top of the script
2. Loop over your images and print out a checkbox for each
3. Add the submit button and close the `</form>`

Comment: But then i would have a button beside every image. I rather have one button at the top that says Delete and it will delete all the pics that have been checked.

Comment: @mario No, the submit button goes after you have finished looping